# Pattern match in binding of lambda?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, sml

In Haskell, I often do something like this:

```
f $ \x -> case x of
            A a1 a2 -> ...
            B b1 b2 -> ...
            C c1 c2 -> ...
```

But I don't want `x`, I just want to deconstruct it.

In Standard ML I can do something like this:

```
f (fn A(a1,a2) => ...
    | B(b1,b2) => ...
    | C(c1,c2) => ...)
```

Is there a way to do this in Haskell or with any GHC extensions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the LambdaCase language extension and perform

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
... 
f $ \case 
     A a1 a2 ->
...
```

as per your example.

You can read more about it [in GHC's documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#lambda-case)

Comment: word I just scrolled through chapter 7 of the manual before making the question and I must of missed this cus I'm too gangsta!